# java.net.UnknownHostException: messages.cucumber.io can't solve in selenium bdd

Tags: selenium, cucumber

When running scripts in Selenium BDD, it was showing error like:

```java
java.net.UnknownHostException: messages.cucumber.io
    
 Error:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: messages.cucumber.io
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.MessageFormatter.writeMessage(MessageFormatter.java:36)
        at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:51)
        at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:12)
```

Comment: what is Selenium bdd? Also can you show full stack trace?

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: messages.cucumber.io` is pretty self-explainatory

Comment: Yes it is selenium bdd.

Comment: @Fenio could you help me to resolve this issue

Comment: You provided `messages.cucumber.io` as a host somewhere. What's expected is an URL to a web page, something like `https://www.google.com`. I can't tell you more without actual code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This has been resolved:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved: after heavy debugging I have identified the root cause:-cucumber was trying to publish the report on cloud which is prevented by the infrastructure. resolved by putting "cucumber.publish.enabled=false" in the properties file. Thank you all for the support